# Trigger Medial Element JS Play with Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I am using the Media Element JS to play some audio on my page. Works great but I would like to be able to have the audio play when a link is clicked, but I cannot figure out how to do this. Here is my code:

***JS***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer();  
});
```

***HTML***

```
<p>Element to Click to Trigger Audio Play</p>

<audio id="player2" src="path.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls></audio>
```

Note: The audio player will be viewable, but due to the layout of the page I am provided an extra way (if possible) for the audio to be played.

Note: I *must* be able to trigger both HTML 5 player and the flash fallback player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278890/play-sound-on-click-using-jquery-and-mediaelement-js) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278890/play-sound-on-click-using-jquery-and-mediaelement-js#answer-11287060) while I kept search SO.

Solution:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    $('audio')[0].player.play();
});
```